# Array shows its pointer instead of its value

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

I'm stuck in some trouble, unfortunately I'm still learning the details of this language.

I have the following code

```c
#define SIZE 5
typedef struct 
{
    int start;
    int end;
    int nElements;
    int vetor[SIZE];
} TSTACK;
```

and I try to inser values in its array using the following function:

```c
void Push(TSTACK *s, int elementInsert)
{
    if(IsFull(s))
    {
        printf("%s\n", "# ERROR: full.");
    }
    else
    {
        s->end++;
        if(s->end == SIZE)
        {
            s->end = 0;
        }

        s->vetor[s->end] = elementInsert;
        s->nElements++;
    }
}
```

and I use the following function to show elements:

```c
void Display(TSTACK *s)
{
    int i;
    if (isEmpty(s))
    {
        printf("%s\n", "# ERROR: empty");
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < s->nElements; i++) 
        {
            printf ("value: %d\n", s->vetor[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is that I don't get the same result when I add different amount of elements, when I insert 5 elements, the Display function display all the elements correctly, but when I insert less than 5, the first item appears to be its pointer:

The following main results in 4201166, 3, 5, 7

```c
int main(void)
{
    TSTACK test;

    test.start = 1;
    test.end = 0;
    test.nElements = 0;

    Push(&test, 3);
    Push(&test, 5);
    Push(&test, 7);
    Push(&test, 3);

    Display(&test);
}
```

The following main results in 5, 3, 5, 7, 3

```c
int main(void)
{
    TSTACK test;

    test.start = 1;
    test.end = 0;
    test.nElements = 0;

    Push(&test, 3);
    Push(&test, 5);
    Push(&test, 7);
    Push(&test, 3);
    Push(&test, 5);

    Display(&test);
}
```

Can someone show me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "insert" an element, you do it at

```
s->vetor[s->end]
```

But before you do that you *increase* `s->end`, so the first element will be at `s->vetor[1]`. Since the first element (`s->vetor[0]`) is not initialized, you will have a random value there. That is the reason you have a strange value first in the four-value insert.

When you insert a fifth value, you have the check for `s->end == SIZE` where you set `s->end` to zero, so the last value in that case will end up in the first place in the array.

The solution, that will solve both of the above problems, is to increase `s->end` *after* you assigned the value to the array.

Comment: What I was trying to say, except better explained

Answer (score 0):

First problem: Local variables aren't initialized, they contain garbage unless you initialize them.

Second problem: You start assigning at array index 1 instead of 0. Only when you insert five elements will it work, because you check if `end == SIZE` and if so set `end = 0`, making the fift insert set the first element `vetor[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you print the stack:

```
for (i = 0; i < s->nElements; i++) 
{
    printf ("value: %d\n", s->vetor[i]);
}
```

You are starting at index 0, but your stack implementation starts at index 1, so when you have less than 5 elements the first item is not initialized. Perhaps you can fix this by changing start value to 0.